# This.props doesn't load data from react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following method:

```
  const getAgentData = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/agent', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(async res => {
          const dbData = res.data.data;
          let dataForTable = dbData.map( el => {
            let obj = {};
            obj._id = el._id;
            obj.name = el.name;
            obj.phone = el.phone;
            if(el.name) {obj.email = el.email}
            return obj;
          })
          await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PHOTOGRAPHERS', dataForTable });
        })
        .then(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
  }
```

I update the redux state with this line: `await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PHOTOGRAPHERS', dataForTable });`

in a child component I run this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.photographers)
  }
```

In the original state this.props.photographers = [];
this is what is logged to the console, it never logs the udpated redux state.  From my understading redux should automatically update and it should console.log the udpated state.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
I also tried logging data with the props being here but it's also an empty array:
class DataTableComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          data: this.props.photographers,
          loading: false,
          name: '',
          phone: '',
          email: '',
      }
  }
...
```

My redux map to props in the child component I'm describing is:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    photographers: state.Customizer.photographers
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataTableComponent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PHOTOGRAPHERS', dataForTable });`, seems that you are not sending the payload correctly. 
You can log or debug how this action payload data is coming to its reducer.